# Entity Framework get single row by LastOrDefault

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

I have a table named `Table1` which has the following columns

```
ID, Foo, Bar, DateTime
```

`ID` is Primary Key

I am trying to get from the table the last row that has `foo` and `bar` that are coming as 
parameters.

I want to get only the the most recent row (sorted by `DateTime`)

```
public void DoIt(string foo, string bar)
{
    using (var context = new DataModelContainer())
    {
        var obj = (from m in context.Table1
                   where m.Foo == foo && m.Bar == bar
                   select m).LastOrDefault();

        if (obj != null)
        {
            DoSomthing()
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`LastOrDefault` is not supported in linq to sql. Use `orderby .. descending` then `FirstOrDefault`.

```
var obj = (from m in context.Table1
           where m.Foo == foo && m.Bar == bar
           orderby m.DateTime descending
           select m).FirstOrDefault();
```